# Create a UIImage by rendering UIWebView on a background thread - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, calayer, cgcontext

Does someone know of a way, or has a creative idea as to how to obtain an UIImage that is rendered from a UIWebView? The catch is, that is must be on a background thread.

I'll elaborate:
I'm trying to obtain the image from multiple UIWebViews every second+-, and display it on screen (iPhone's of course). Because rendering a layer to a CGContext is a CPU consuming job, I wouldn't like to use the main thread, so not to hang the UI.

My attempts so far were:

- I tried to use `renderInContext` on the webView's layer to the `UIGraphicalContext`, but the `_WebTryThreadLock` error crashed the webviews.
- I tried creating a `CGBitmapContext`, and render the webview's layer to it, but got the same result.
- I tried implementing a `copy` method (by adding a Category) to `CALayer`, that deep copied all of the public properties, and sublayers. Afterwards, I tried to `renderInContext` the layer I copied. I got a UIImage that was **partially** "correct" - meaning, not all of the layers were rendered, so for example, i would get only the website header (or footer, or body, or search bar, or just a some of the frames). The UIWebview's layer consists of all sort of subclassed CALayers, so this is probably why this approached didn't work.
- I tried setting the `kCATransactionDisableActions` in a `CATransaction`, but it didn't appear to change this behavior (neither of them).

I'm pretty close to giving up.

Is there a savior among you people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIWebView hates, and I mean *really hates*, having anything done to it on a background thread. UIKit is not fully thread safe. Drawing to a graphics context is (this was added in iOS 4), but not creating UIViews on a secondary thread.

Are you creating your UIWebViews off the main thread? Do you perhaps have some code to share? I would suspect your issues are being caused by the fact you're trying to perform operations to a UIWebView on a secondary thread. The drawing operation to render the view's contents as an image *can* happen off the main thread, but creating the view itself can't.

Comment: I'm creating the UIWebViews on the main thread. I couldn't agree more about the "hates" part ;), and I also agree that drawing to a graphics context is possible, but unfortunately, it seems as rendering the UIWebView layout seems to lock, in certain conditions, the thread associated with the UIWebView itself (not the main thread, but the one that iOS creates to handle it), which causes it to freak out when the locking is done by a secondary thread. The UIWebView layout is build with a few private API subclasses of CALayer (WebLayer etc.).

Comment: I've seen similar issues before with webviews, although they've also been confined to the simulator - you're right, it's probably to do with one of the private subclasses. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this, too.

In a thread I create a view hierarchy, loop until the web-view has finished loading content.

The webview I create is inside of a UIViewController's viewdidload-- I've tried doing

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread] == NO) {[self performselectorOnMainThread: @selector(viewDidLoad)return;)}
```

And I've done the same for dealloc'ing the webView.

But that didn't work.. I've only found that we avoid UIWebView exceptions UNTIL we hit the autorelease pool...

I'm using instruments to figure out *why*.

Here's my attack strategy... 
I'm going to perform the render operation on the main thread with an off-screen view, having a separate thread running some sort of queue to manage them. I'm worried about UI lag, so it'll have to be fairly efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that's the trick... Perform selectors to create the render on a separate thread, query the loading status on a subsidiary thread, then render on main thread when ready.

Comment: That's basically my current solution. But it's not a good one, as I do have too much UI lag because of it (and the only thing I do on the main thread is the actual core rendering process).