# Must Webkit always be used on the main thread?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, webkit

I'm trying to render webpages in the background and I ran into the following trouble

```
2012-05-11 12:39:02.086 [77207:1c03] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-05-11 12:39:02.087 [77207:1c03] objc_object* -[WebView initWithFrame:frameName:groupName:](WebView*, objc_selector*, CGRect, NSString*, NSString*) was called from a secondary thread
```

I understand that webkit classes are not thread-safe, but do they also have to be always used from the main thread? Alternatively, can I create a dummy web view just to initialize webkit and then later use webkit classes from background threads?

Comment: Looks like no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660999/create-a-uiimage-by-rendering-uiwebview-on-a-background-thread-iphone

Comment: @Jeremy1026 That post concerns UIWebView, not WebView.

Comment: WebViews load asynchronously. What are you hoping to gain by shifting that to a background thread?

Comment: @Tony Have you actually found a solution on how to do this?

Comment: I worked around the problem instead of actually solving it. I would initialize webkit in a background process if I need to do processing, otherwise there doesn't seem to be a way to use it from a background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebView` is a subclass of `NSView`.  From the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html):

> The NSView class is generally thread-safe, with a few exceptions. **You
>   should create, destroy, resize, move, and perform other operations on
>   NSView objects only from the main thread of an application.** Drawing
>   from secondary threads is thread-safe as long as you bracket drawing
>   calls with calls to lockFocusIfCanDraw and unlockFocus.

(Emphasis added.)

I'm less clear on how the AppKit `WebView` works, but my understanding is that in UIKit there is really only one `UIWebView` that just gets reused all over for performance reasons, something akin to the field editor in AppKit.  If my understanding is correct, and `WebView` behaves similarly, I could see you having even bigger problems with background threading.

Comment: Yea, looks like performing webkit work in background is best done in a separate process rather than a separate thread. Do you know if it is possible to pre-load webpages without rendering in the background? That way one can have a single web view doing the rendering but network requests can still be concurrent.

Comment: To be honest I'm not that practiced with AppKit WebView, but at worst you could download the pages asynchronously with NSHTTPURLConnection, then load the contents into the WebView with, e.g., -[WebFrame loadHTMLString:baseURL:].

Comment: @Tony - you could use multiple webviews, preloading pages into ones which are not currently visible - think Safari tabs.