# Explicitly setting the datasource for WebFrame

Tags: cocoa, asynchronous, webview

Is it possible to manually create WebDataSource objects and then set the created object to be the datasource of a webFrame object? I can't seem to find a method on WebFrame class that allows the setting of datasource. The goal is to asynchronously pre-load webpages without having to render them in a web view all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an offscreen WebView. It'll load the resources for you and not waste time drawing itself.

Answer (score 1):

(I gather this is a follow-up to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555403/must-webkit-always-be-used-on-the-main-thread/10555657) I answered a little while ago?)

As I alluded to in my comment on that question, you use one of the `-[WebFrame load...]` methods to load content.  When you issue the load request the WebView instantiates a `-provisionalDataSource` which in turn becomes the `-dataSource` (so much for clear naming!).  As the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html) summarizes:

> The provisional data source transitions to a committed data source
>   once any data is received.

Unless you are extending WebKit, I don't think there is usually a reason to create `WebDataSource` instances directly. Let `WebFrame` do it for you.

Comment: yea this is a follow up question. Would you say that the right solution is to manually create web frames then attach to web view for rendering?

Comment: Or just instantiate a `WebView`, access its `mainFrame` and do an in-place update?

Comment: that would require waiting for one page to load and finish processing before beginning to load the next page though. Only one network request would be out at a time, latency would kill performance.

Comment: I thought you were going to pre-fetch the contents? You don't have to have WebKit actually perform the download.

Comment: the problem is that without using webkit any prefetching would be incomplete. `NSURLRequest` for example won't load a webpage's associated resources.

Comment: Ah, true. So ignore what I said - go with your WebFrame idea.