# Background Thread SnapShot of UICollectionViewCell = WebCore Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsoperationqueue, uicollectionviewcell

The original problem I was trying to solve was how to take a screenshot of a UICollectionViewCell without jamming up the UI. I found a solution that works for taking a snapshot of a given cell on a background thread, the only problem is that if the snapshot request doesn't get executed before the cell is deallocated, it hangs out in the queue and eventually causes a crash.

**[EDIT]** I just discovered that the problem has something to do with the fact that the cells contain a UIWebView. I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from WebCore when I run the following code.  **When I attempt to take a background snapshot of each cell without the UIWebView, it works fine.**

Can anyone determine what about UIWebView/WebCore would cause this issue and/or how I might solve it?

Here is the code:

In my UICollectionViewCell subclass, I created a singleton instance of NSOperationQueue:

```
+ (NSOperationQueue*)sharedSnapshotOperation
  {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static NSOperationQueue *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        shared.name =  @"Snapshot Queue";
        shared.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    });
    return shared;
  }
```

In the same subclass, I have the following method defined for taking my snapshot:

```
- (void) snapshotAsync:(ImageOutBlock)block
  {
    CGFloat scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    __weak CALayer *layer = self.layer;

    NSBlockOperation *newBlockOperation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc]init];
    [newBlockOperation addExecutionBlock:^{

        //TAKE SNAPSHOT OF CELL 
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, frame.size.width * scaleFactor, frame.size.height * scaleFactor, 8, frame.size.width * scaleFactor * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES /*opaque*/, scaleFactor);
        [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        CGContextRelease(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        //GET MAIN QUEUE FOR DOING ULTIMATE TASK
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
         block(image);
      }];
  }];

    self.blockOperation = newBlockOperation;

    //ADD OPERATION TO QUEUE
    [[InboxCell sharedSnapshotOperation] addOperation:self.blockOperation];
}
```

Again, in the same subclass, I declared the block that is passed into my async snapshot method:

```
typedef void(^ImageOutBlock)(UIImage* image);
```

Again, in the same subclass I call the above async snapshot method like so:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf snapshotAsync:^(UIImage* image) {

      //PUT THE IMAGE IN THE CACHE (ultimate task)
      [weakSelf.delegate setCellScreenShot:image forKey:[weakSelf makeIndexingKeyForScreenShot]];
    }];
```

Finally, my attempt to cancel the operation request if the cell is about to be deallocated (called from the UICollectionView delegate):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell: (UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       InboxCell *inboxCell = (InboxCell *)cell;
       [inboxCell.blockOperation cancel];
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: the layer's delegate is the view. You need to ensure that the view won't be deallocated as long as you use the layer.

Comment: This question answered my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660999/create-a-uiimage-by-rendering-uiwebview-on-a-background-thread-iphone

Answer (score 0):

did you try creating your own custom NSOperation?

The idea would be keep a strong pointer in your cell to the NSOperation that will take an screenshot of it. When your cell is going to be reuse (method prepareForReuse) or deallocated verify the status of the NSOperation (isFinished property) and if it doesn't just cancel it.

I would suggest to create your own queue in the UICollectionView delegate and process the operations in other thread.

Give a look to the NSOperation API Doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html